# \COPY not returning count psql

Tags: postgresql, import, csv

I am trying to copy CSV data into tables. Also I want to print the count.
The command I'm using is:

```
echo "begin; delete from a; \copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER; end;" | psql -hlocalhost -dpostgres -Upostgres
```

Expected Output:

```
BEGIN
DELETE 2
COPY 2
COMMIT
```

Actual Output:

```
BEGIN
DELETE 2
COMMIT
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try to use `'\\'` separator meta-command: `echo "delete from a; \\ \copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER" | psql -hlocalhost -dpostgres -Upostgres`

Comment: @Akina I've tried using '\\' it's still not working. Interestingly, this works - `echo -e "begin;\ndelete from a;\n\\\copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER;\nend;" | psql -hlocalhost -dpostgres -Upostgres`. I'm flummoxed to start using `\n` characters in my scripts. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the `COPY 2` is missing

As said in [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) about `\copy`:

> Unlike most other meta-commands, the entire remainder of the line is
>   always taken to be the arguments of \copy

Clearly your intention is that `COPY` and `END` commands are sent consecutively, but in fact the SQL command that is sent to the server and successfully executed is the compound statement:

```
COPY a FROM STDIN CSV HEADER; end;
```

That does work, but when dealing with the results of compound statements, psql only handles the last one, as mentioned in `Backslash-semicolon`:

> psql prints only the last query result it receives for each request

The expected `COPY 2` command tag is not displayed, because it's the first of two results of a compound statement: `COPY` and `COMMIT`.

### Workarounds

The simplest one is probably to use `-1` or `--single-transaction` as an argument to psql to make it enclose the sequence of commands inside a transaction:

```
echo "delete from a; \copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER" | psql -1 [other options]
```

With this form, the end of the line is clear so `\copy` can consume it. Plus that's why `-1` is made for.

Another option if you had to put other commands after the `\copy` anyway: use the [heredoc syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
$ psql [options] << ENDOFCOMMANDS
begin;
delete from a;
\copy a from a.csv CSV HEADER
-- other commands
end;
ENDOFCOMMANDS
```